# Which gem is requiring a gem bundler can't install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to update a gem using `bundler` (`middleman-s3_sync` from `3.0.30` to `~> 4.0`), but it's trying to install a version of `net-ssh` that requires Ruby 2, while I'm still at 1.9.3.

So I want to know if there's any version I can lock down in any dependency so I don't have to update to Ruby 2 by now.

I'd like to see something like *how will the `Gemfile.lock` file will look like after the update*, but without actually performing the update.

How can I get that?

I've [tried `bundle install --verbose`](https://gist.github.com/matiasgarciaisaia/776363f60f7875934825) to see what's going on, but it just queries RubyGems with an array of gem names and gets back another array of dependencies - without telling which one belongs to the other.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
$ gem --version
1.8.23
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.9.0
```

Comment: @JesseSielaff: The question still has sense with different not-EOLed dependencies, anyway, I think.